# How to transform one object to another only under certain circumstances without any cloning?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, and have come across something quite simple that I'm struggling with.

I'm trying to change one struct into another if it matches a certain criteria, and otherwise leave it unchanged.

The example below is silly, but based on a problem I encountered "for real" (https://github.com/swc-project/swc/pull/5179#issuecomment-1209398758).

In this example, I have a pet who may be a dog or a cat. If my pet is a male dog, I would like to switch them for a female cat, and they'll keep the same name. But otherwise, I'll keep the pet I have.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

enum Pet {
    Cat(Cat),
    Dog(Dog),
}

struct Cat {
    name: Arc<str>,
    gender: Gender,
}

struct Dog {
    name: Arc<str>,
    gender: Gender,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female,
}

fn change_pet(mut pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    if let Pet::Dog(ref dog) = pet {
        if dog.gender == Gender::Male {
            pet = Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: dog.name.clone(), // <-- cloning
                gender: Gender::Female,
            });
        }
    }
    pet
}

pub fn main() {
    let mut pet = Pet::Dog(Dog {
        name: Arc::<str>::from("rover"),
        gender: Gender::Male,
    });
    pet = change_pet(pet);
    println!(
        "I own a {}",
        match pet {
            Pet::Cat(_) => "cat",
            Pet::Dog(_) => "dog",
        }
    );
}
```

The code above works, but it seems inefficient. In `change_pet`, I have to borrow `dog` because otherwise `pet` is consumed and I can't return it unchanged if the pet is already a cat. Therefore when I come to create the new `Cat`, I have to clone `name` (because `Arc<str>` is not `Copy`) where it could just be moved. Cloning `Arc<str>` is not completely inexpensive and requires synchronization across threads.

Another approach which doesn't involve borrowing is:

```rust
fn change_pet(pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    match pet {
        Pet::Dog(dog) => match dog.gender {
            Gender::Male => Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: dog.name,
                gender: dog.gender,
            }),
            Gender::Female => Pet::Dog(dog),
        },
        cat => cat,
    }
}
```

This takes ownership of `dog` and therefore doesn't need to clone `name`. But this version has 2 disadvantages:

1. It's not as clear to read.
2. If the pet is a female dog, a new `Pet` has to be created (kind of the same problem again in a different form).

Is there no way to say to Rust "forget about `pet` and give me an owned reference to `dog` now"?

Or am I worrying too much? Will the compiler compile away the `.clone()` call?

Comment: Rust Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=aa931617d89a0b7fa2dcd1fdc8a1f3fa

Comment: Were you using `Arc` just to avoid cloning a `String` or are actually sharing something between threads here?

Comment: This is a made-up example. I just used `Arc<str>` to signify a structure which has a cost to cloning it.

Comment: I probably should have just posted my real case! It is here: https://github.com/swc-project/swc/pull/5179#issuecomment-1209398758

Answer (score 4):

The `match` approach is fine, and you can use a guard to handle the case you want to transform (male dog) while passing the others through:

```
fn change_pet(pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    match pet {
        Pet::Dog(dog) if dog.gender == Gender::Male =>
            Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: dog.name,
                gender: dog.gender,
            }),
        other => other,
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing by pattern-matching the gender and destructuring the dog into just its `name` field:

```
fn change_pet(pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    match pet {
        Pet::Dog(Dog { name, gender: Gender::Male }) =>
            Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: name,
                gender: Gender::Male,
            }),
        other => other,
    }
}
```

Or by pattern-matching the gender and capturing the entire dog value with `@` bindings:

```
fn change_pet(pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    match pet {
        Pet::Dog(dog @ Dog { gender: Gender::Male, .. }) =>
            Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: dog.name,
                gender: dog.gender,
            }),
        other => other,
    }
}
```

In all of these cases, the first match arm only matches male dogs, and the catch-all `other => other` arm will match anything else (female dogs, and all cats) passing them through unmodified.  Which specific type of pattern you prefer is a matter of taste.

Comment: But... it seems I simplified my example too much. My real world case is more like: `enum Pet { Dog(Box<Dog>), Cat(Box<Cat>) }`. Is there any way to handle dereferencing the `Box` too?

Comment: @OverlookMotel Not in one step. You'll have to match on `Pet::Dog(dog)` and then do `match *dog { Dog { ... } => ..., _ => Pet::Dog(dog)`, like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=6ac3a7d566ee5417e377494898b348ff

Comment: @OverlookMotel Yes, the first example (with the `if` match guard) works almost verbatim, you just need to add a call to `Box::new` for the resulting `Cat` value: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0446b08764855f34ee216b5510cc1c0f

Answer (score 1):

@cdhowie's answer is excellent and definitely the way to go here, I just want to take this opportunity to highlight a very useful [Rust design pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/idioms/mem-replace.html#memtake_-replace_-to-keep-owned-values-in-changed-enums) that solves a related problem and might come up in a similar circumstance.

Let's say you wanted to change your pet in place this time, only having access to it through a mutable reference:

```
fn change_pet_in_place(pet: &mut Pet) { ...
```

The destructuring approach won't work here; `pet.name` will be a `&mut String` (I've simplified the field to a `String` instead of a `Arc<str>`<sup>1</sup>) and we can't just move it out and into our new `Cat`'s `name` field.

But we can use `std::mem::take`(/`std::mem::replace`) to yoink it out of a `Dog`, leaving an empty `String` in its place (which won't allocate):

```
fn change_pet_in_place(pet: &mut Pet) {
    match pet {
        Pet::Dog(Dog { name, gender: Gender::Male }) =>
            *pet = Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: std::mem::take(name),
                gender: Gender::Female,
            }),
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: As @cdhowie also quite rightly pointed out, this *won't* actually work for an `Arc` because it has no `Default` implementation and there's nothing you could `replace` it with that wouldn't also have to allocate. So this is more of a general illustration of the pattern.

Comment: @cdhowie Good call, that's definitely of note. But then again `Arc`s are designed to be cloned anyways, so I feel like this wouldn't be the primary use case of this pattern in the first place. I wonder though if you could trick the compiler with some `MaybeUninit` magic without going to UB hell...

Comment: https://docs.rs/replace_with/latest/replace_with/fn.replace_with_or_abort.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to match with `unreachable!()` if we found the pet is of the wanted type:

```rust
pub fn change_pet(mut pet: Pet) -> Pet {
    if let Pet::Dog(ref dog) = pet {
        if dog.gender == Gender::Male {
            pet = Pet::Cat(Cat {
                name: match pet {
                    Pet::Dog(Dog { name, .. }) => name,
                    _ => unreachable!(),
                },
                gender: Gender::Female,
            });
        }
    }
    pet
}
```

[The compiler optimizes the panic away](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/YhK153z7j) (although it may not be always able to).